# Tooltip for a line of text

Tags: html, xhtml

```
<td title="this is a really long line that I'm going to truncate">this is a really long line that I'm going to trunc ...</td>
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The `title` attribute doesn't work inside the `td` tag. Enclose the text within a span tag instead:

```
<td>
    <span title="this is a really long line that I'm going to truncate">this is a really long line that I'm going to trunc ...</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a maximum length for the title. It's around 80 characters (tested on FF2).

So if your text is really long the title won't help. There are several good css/javascript tooltip solutions that will show whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how you supposed to assign tooltips to html elements. I wouldn't use it on <td> though. Although I haven't tested it, I have the feeling that you might run into issues on some browsers if you use it on table rows/cells directly since these elements have somewhat different behaviour from other elements. You should rather  use it on more "regular" elements, for example <div>, <span>, <img>  or <input>.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DrJokepu, the `title` attribute is the way to do this, but probably not on the `TD` element, try the `ABBR` element, that's what it's for, or failing that, a simple `SPAN` is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

How would you format the text to show a line break? In IE 7.0

```
<title="long line of text\nanotherlong line of text" />
```

works as expected - but in Firefix 3.01 the "\n" is changed to a space. Using `<br/>` doesn't help either.

Comment: I believe it is not part of the HTML spec.
Anyway, FF3, IE6 and Opera 9.50 (and probably lot of other browsers/versions) display automatically long tooltips on several lines.

Answer (score 0):

FF2 has a bug preventing it from displaying long titles: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45375

Isn't title a core attribute? So it is valid on pretty much every tag (bar few eg. html, head etc.)

Comment: Yes, it is a core attribute like id, class and style, and title on td works on FF3, IE6 and Opera 9.50 at least. I don't see why people want to restrict it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want some control over the tooltip you could try modifying this to your needs 
[css Tooltip](http://evolutionarygoo.com/blog/?p=45)